# Issue with processing form i ajax with radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I have this script which makes possible the insertion of some data using ajax and php.

Now , all works fine, except the radio buttons (the select options work fine as well) , and it takes the first value of the radio buttons..

Why is this happening?
Here is the code:

```
<div id="formfields" ><label>Tipologia Pdv: </label>
<input type="radio" name="tipologia_pdv" id="tipologia_pdv" value="Iper" style="width:40px;" /><span > Iper</span>
<input type="radio" name="tipologia_pdv" id="tipologia_pdv"
value="Super" style="width:40px;" /><span > Super</span><br /><br /></div>
<div id="formfields" ><label>Richiesta Ccnl: </label>
<input type="radio" name="richiesta_ccnl" id="richiesta_ccnl" value="Si" style="width:40px;"/><span> Si</span>
<input type="radio" name="richiesta_ccnl" id="richiesta_ccnl"
value="No" style="width:40px;"/><span> No</span><br /><br /></div>
```

The javascript:

```
// Fetch data from input fields.
var js_tipologia_pdv = $("#tipologia_pdv").val();
var js_richiesta_ccnl = $("#richiesta_ccnl").val();

//let's put all data together
var myData = 'postTipologia_pdv='+ js_tipologia_pdv + '&postRichiesta_ccnl='+ js_richiesta_ccnl + '&postDistretto_pdv=' + js_distretto_pdv + '&postCoopva_pdv=' + js_coopva_pdv + '&postNome_pdv=' + js_nome_pdv;
```

In php they go something like this:

```
$postTipologia_pdv      = filter_var($_POST["postTipologia_pdv"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$postRichiesta_ccnl     = filter_var($_POST["postRichiesta_ccnl"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: For starters, your id attributes need to be unique.  I'm not sure if that's your whole problem, but it might be.

Comment: Hi Todd, thanks for your reply... well, maybe it's that, but how would i get it?.. thanks

Comment: `$('input:radio[name=tipologia_pdv]:checked').val();`...or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the idea :)
It was something like this, and you should have answered so i would have accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comments into an answer:

1) Your `id` attributes need to be unique.

2) Get the value of the selected radio button using something like: `$('input:radio[name=tipologia_pdv]:checked').val();`